# How to determine x-axis if the two z-axis are parallel in Denavit Hartenberg representation

Tags: first-robotics

I have problem of determining the DH table, specially finding x axis when two z axis are parallel to each other

Comment: Are you trying to apply DH to frames that don't have a DH representation/solution?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* @OptimusPrime.  Can you provide more detail?   We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Make them parallel to the previous X Axis. This helps reducing the number of non-zero coordinates in the DH table which in turn means less + and * operations in the calculations.